# Xcode 10 - Unable to view element tree in console using po

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10, ios-ui-automation, xcuitest

I recently upgraded to Xcode 10 and when trying to debug my UI tests, I typically use `po XCUIApplication()`.  This will not print out the tree for me now?  I can only get it to display in the console if I edit the code to include `print(XCUIApplication().debugDescription)` before my debug point.  I also tried putting `po XCUIApplication().debugDescription` within the console window but that only prints the same two lines shown here:
[image]

Any suggestions for how to get it to appear again in the console without using the debug line in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Determined this was due to 'All Output' being selected instead of 'Debugger Output' in the bottom left of the console window.

[image]